# Access Private member function of a class

Tags: c++

I have a class A having a number of Private/Public member functions/variables. I have added a new private member function to it. As part of a testing the newly added method, I need to invoke the private member function from my test class. In the case of member variables I have seen an example like below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
   private:
          int myInt;
   public:
          int getInt () {return myInt;}
};

int main ()
{
   test t;
   int* p = (int*) & t;
   *p = 20;
    cout << t.getInt ();
}
Output:20
```

Is there any reliable way I can access the private member function such that there is no code modification in the class `A`?

Comment: _" such that there is no code modification in the class A?"_ Nope!

Comment: No, either you use dirty tricks (probably U.B.) like the one you are using in the example code you provided, or you tweak the class. (BTW, I see no class A in your code.)

Comment: As you've shown, there are ways, but you'll wind up hanging out with unseemly types, method hookers in platform-dependent shoes, and data dealers pushing used libraries. If it's for unit testing, you have more options, as rightfold points too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change class access modifiers with macro `#define private public` for testing, but it isn't good idea. I think you need to review test approach